# Can't access files in the internal storage

Tags: java, android, storage

I'm trying to build an Activity that allows the user to select a picture in his gallery and to send it to my Web Server (who perfectly receives files from another php web page).
The problem is : before the app can try to make the request, the code returns an error : can't access to the file.

Before I changed my code, I had

```
EACESS(Permissions Denied)
```

Now I just have what my code prints.

```
E/uploadFile: Source File not exist :
```

So here's my code :

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        final Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    }
                });

                uploadFile(selectedImage.toString());

            }
        }).start();
    }
}
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    verifyStoragePermissions(ScanActivity.this);
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {


        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            }
        });

        return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL("http://82.237.124.168/Legimetrie/reception_intervention_scan.php");

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\";filename=\""
                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/";

                        Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

And here is my Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.partenaires.legimetrie.legimetrieapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".InscriptionActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ConnexionActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ServicesActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".InterventionRapideActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".InterventionDetailleeActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ScanActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ContactActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Can you maybe help me to get the error please ?

(PS : I would like to precise that I don't want to access to the external storage but the error (I guess) is External Access (Permission Denied), so there's something I'm doing wrong)

Comment: Have you added permissions to access storage in your Manifest file?

Comment: Yes I did, I edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android M version you need to request for certain permissions at runtime. This should help you:

[Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Comment: It's done by the function verifyStoragePermissions and I'm not working with external storage but it's an external access error ...

Comment: Of course you are. What do you think that pictures shown by the agallery app reside else? Have a look at the value of `String picturePath`. And if you have such an external -storage- access error you should post the logcat.

Comment: I took a look at the path, and it's "content://media/external/images/media/4794" I don't really understand this path. Can you help me ?

Comment: That is a content provider path. Not a file system path. It is equal to Uri selectedImage.getPath().

Comment: I meant : why is there a "external" written in the path if my files aren't in the external storage (sorry if I don't understand something, english is not my first language)